# What price would you pay for remote eye-tracking services?

Tags: eye-tracking

What price would you pay for remote eye-tracking services? (per capita)

Considering the following

- results delivered in 24 hours
- reliability of the test would be arond 80-90%
- pricing based on per capita figures
- tests done with real people (not software generated)

And what kind of results would you like to get?

- video recordings?
- heatmaps?
- fixation order maps?

Pricing strategy would be really flexible: you have to pay only for what you ask!

or do you need this kind of service at all???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by defining who your concurrents would be and check what their pricing plans are, that will already give you an idea of what potential customers might expect.

Also, the question may fit better [OnStartups.SE](http://answers.onstartups.com) instead because that's imho a business model question.